# Bug in the ListenOrderService (notifications) in my app

Tags: java, android

I'm testing a delivery android app, and I've got a bug in the Notifications System. When it had only one restaurant, it was all working good, but when I changed to multiple restaurants, it stopped appearing the notifications, either for server side when a client makes a new order, also for the client when the server updates the order. Look at my Order Status Service (Server Side):

```
public class OrderStatusService extends Service {

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    public OrderStatusService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Restaurants").child(Common.restaurantSelected)
                .child("Request");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Request request = dataSnapshot.getValue(Request.class);
                assert request != null;
                if(request.getPhone().equals(Common.currentUser.getPhone()))
                    showNotification(dataSnapshot.getKey(), request);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    //Helper method
    private void showNotification(String key, Request request) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), OrderStatusActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("phone", request.getPhone());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                (getBaseContext(), 0,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setTicker("ParisCart")
                .setContentTitle("Pedido Atualizado")
                .setContentText("Pedido #" + key + " foi atualizado para " + Common.getStatus(request.getStatus()))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_access_time_black_24dp);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        firebaseDatabase = null;
        databaseReference = null;
    }
}
```

Same thing for client at the Order Listen Service:

```
public class OrderListenService extends Service {

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    public OrderListenService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Restaurants").child(Common.restaurantSelected)
                .child("Request");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Request request = dataSnapshot.getValue(Request.class);
                assert request != null;
                if(request.getStatus().equals("0") && request.getPhone().equals(Common.currentUser.getPhone()))
                    showNotification(dataSnapshot.getKey(), request);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    //Helper method
    private void showNotification(String key, Request request) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), OrderStatusActivityServer.class);
        intent.putExtra("phone", request.getPhone());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                (getBaseContext(), 0,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setTicker("ParisCart")
                .setContentTitle("Pedido Novo")
                .setContentText("Pedido #" + key + " adicionado")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_access_time_black_24dp);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.notify(2, builder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        firebaseDatabase = null;
        databaseReference = null;
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's something at Firebase, or one little thing, like currentUser, restaurantSelected, etc...

Comment: When you say stop working you mean only one notification/order status is visible at any time

Comment: No, when it was only one restaurant, all notifications were coming, now with multiple don't comes any notifications (sorry if english's bad)